# Deserialize string contains int with comma

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

I can't deserialize number with comma in json to int. It throw this exception :

**Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException : 'Could not convert string to integer: 24,992. Path 'Requests', line 1**

This is my code :

```
public class PriceModel
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int Requests { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
string json = "{\"Date\":\"2018-03-23\",\"Requests\":\"24,992\",\"Price\":\"95.96\"}";

PriceModel value = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PriceModel>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Culture = new CultureInfo("en-US")
});
```

I want that the "Requests" property have the value 24992.

Is there a solution to resolve this problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Yes. Get rid of the comma.

Comment: Make sure you are using a culture with a comma as thousand separator.

Comment: Notice that the number is actually surrounded in quotes, meaning it's actually a string. You're going to have to manually parse this I'm afraid.

Comment: Do you control the generation of the JSON object or no?

Comment: @DanRevell it's the only solution ? It's a little bit ugly..

Comment: @itsme86 I d'ont control the generation of the JSON

Comment: Yeah, whoever owns the API is totally boning you.

Comment: @NathanBruet checkout the solution I added. It works as you needed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok after some research came up with following solution where you don't need to change any type or anything and it works as per your requirement.

While deserializing don't use return type `var` instead use `PriceModel` and then other things will remain same.

Create new Class `ProcessChildModel` which inherits from `ProcessModel` and overrides `Requests` property.

```
    public class PriceModel
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public int Requests { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }

    public class PriceModelChild : PriceModel
    {
        public new string Requests
        {
            set
            {
                int num;
                if (int.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.AllowThousands,
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out num))
                {
                    base.Requests = num;
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Then use the new child model to deserialize the data

```
string json = "{\"Date\":\"2018-03-23\",\"Requests\":\"24,992\",\"Price\":\"95.96\"}";
PriceModel value = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PriceModelChild>(json);
```

Answer (score 1):

Redefine your class:

```
public class PriceModel
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Requests { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

Because the data type `int` cannot handle the comma. Once the object is deserialized, you can then remove the comma:

```
int requests;
int.TryParse(value.Requests.Replace(",",""), out requests);
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution.
I think it's the last one for my problem but it's not pretty..

Comment: Sometimes the best solution isn't the prettiest, unfortunately. If this answer addresses your issue, you can accept by clicking the check mark.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue today and came up with a different solution.

First, define a `JsonConverter<int>` that accepts the format.

```
public sealed class ThousandsIntConverter : JsonConverter<int>
{
    public override int ReadJson(
        JsonReader reader,
        Type objectType,
        int existingValue,
        bool hasExistingValue,
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
        {
            throw new JsonSerializationException("Cannot unmarshal int");
        }

        var value = (string)reader.Value;
        const NumberStyles style = NumberStyles.AllowThousands;
        var result = int.Parse(value, style, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        return result;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, int value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(value);
    }
}
```

Now add the `[JsonConverter(typeof(ThousandsIntConverter))]` attribute to the property that you want converted.

The property will be serialized even if it contains commas and it will be deserialized without them.